# What is the benefit with migration from barrel imports to individual imports in angular material 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

material
Breaking changes:

Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as @angular/material/button.

source: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#material-14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main benefit - **Performance**

When you import like:

```js
import perfrunner from 'perfrunner'
```

You importing the whole library into your code.

If you don't have tree shaking or it works not good enough - your application bundle might be significantly increased. This will lead to performance issues because bigger bundles load slower and parse slower. This is especially painful when you are using only 10% of the imported code and the library is big.

For this reason, lot's of libraries designed to support individual imports (like above) to allow you to use only things you really need.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using angular 9 with angular cli so I should have tree-shaking by default, right? and it shouldn't affect performance for me? e.g. from migration from angular 8 to angular 9 bundle size which is associated with the material will be not changed

Comment: You are partially right. Yes, you already have tree-shaking. But tree-shaking is not a kind of magic. Code you wont to shake should also support this, or, at least, doesn't prevent.
Check this article for more information https://dev.to/lukasbombach/how-to-write-a-tree-shakable-component-library-4ied